# "npm run" on Windows "cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, mocha.js

In my Node.js project I have a script in my package.json file that runs the tests using mocha like so:

```
"scripts": {

    "test": "mocha --reporter list spec/*",

    "test:cov": "istanbul cover _mocha -R spec && open coverage/lcov-report/index.html"
  },
```

I just tried to run the test script on my Windows machine by running:

```
npm run test
```

and I get the following message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\[User]\Projects\Leaflet-LightCluster\spec\setup'
```

I decided to test if it was an issue with mocha by installing mocha globally (i.e. `npm install -g mocha`) and when I run the same command that is contained in the "test" script everything runs and works fine.

At work I use a Mac and have never had this issue. In fact I can run the same `npm` command on the same project on my Mac and it works. I'm working on some personal projects on my personal Windows machine and therefore assume this is a Windows issue?

Can anyone verify that this is a Windows issue? 
Also has anyone encountered this issue and knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the configuration I use in both windows and unix environment with mocha installed locally:

```
"test": "istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec --full-trace --trace ./test/**/*.spec.js"
```

you can review it here [Link](https://github.com/asa-git/forked-worker-pool) through the config there is more complicated as I need to cover forked instances.

Comment: I guess the issue was that it didn't know that their were subfolders within the spec folder.  Adding:

./spec/**/*.js

worked for both the test and coverage scripts.

Thanks for the help!